# Could not find config for 'django' in settings.TEMPLATES

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, settings

I wrote a script that takes a JSON file as input and tries to render a very basic HTML template using Django. In order to generate the HTML file I have to acces the specific url that generates the file , in my case localhost:8000/generate_html/.

I am working in a virtual environment.

However, when I try to do that I get the following error message:

[Server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx4lN.png)

My script looks like this :

```
# Required imports
import json
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import engines
from django.urls import path 

# Django settings configuration
settings.configure(
   DEBUG=True,
   SECRET_KEY='your_secret_key',
   ALLOWED_HOSTS=['localhost'],
   ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
   TEMPLATES=[
       {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
           'DIRS': [],
           'APP_DIRS': True,
       },
   ],
)

# Django view function
def generate_html(request):
   # Read JSON file
   with open('input.json') as json_file:
       data = json.load(json_file)

   # Load template from file
   with open('template.html') as template_file:
       template_content = template_file.read()

   # Render the template with JSON data
   template = engines['django'].from_string(template_content)
   html = template.render(data)

   # Write the rendered HTML to a file
   with open('output.html', 'w') as html_file:
       html_file.write(html)

   return HttpResponse('HTML file generated successfully!')

# URL configuration
def index(request):
   return HttpResponse('Welcome to the Django script!')

urlpatterns = [
   path('', index),
   path('generate_html/', generate_html),
]

# Django application setup
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
if __name__ == "__main__":
   execute_from_command_line()
```

My JSON file looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKDXg.png)

And this is my template file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0arl.png)

I imagine I have to make django detect my template file as a template by somehow adding it to it's templates files.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: No, I don't think that's the issue. It's more likely to be how you run the code. I couldn't understand why you call configure here, why are you using views and what is "application setup" in the end. Generally I don't understand what are you doing with all this code, what was the desired workflow?

Comment: @GinFuyou neither do I really :) I just followed some tutorials I saw online , basically I try to open a json file, load it's content into a variable and then load a template , render it into HTML file with the JSON data previously stored.
The way I would run this program would be by opening GitBASH and executing ' python <my script name>.py runserver ' 

This was meant to be a whole django webapp wrote into one singular file, that's why the configure  and application setup are all in the same file. 
I am a newbie to django... and web dev in general :)

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not following the reasoning. How you want code to operate? Web works with client-server model, you start the server, then it's waiting for client requests. Scripts don't work that way, `python <script>.py runserver` doesn't really make sense.